# How to get a list of links to the xml?

Tags: php, html, dom, xml-parsing

**The XML file:**

```
<urlset>
    <url>
         <loc>http://example.com/.../</loc>
         <lastmod>0000-00-00</lastmod>
         <priority>0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
         <loc>http://example.com/...</loc>
         <lastmod>0000-00-00</lastmod>
         <priority>0</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

How to get a list of links to the xml? (google translate)

```
foreach ($html->find('?????') as $element) {
    echo $element->src;
}
```

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php/3577662#3577662

Comment: To the XML??? So you want to parse the XML file? Or what do you try.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a list of all "loc" elements.

```
$simpleObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$loc = $simpleObj->xpath('//loc');

foreach($loc as $url){
    echo $url;
}
```